# Envío de mail automáticos en Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cronjobs

Estoy almacenando en una tabla de mi proyecto los carrito abandonados. Para que cuando pase una hora y un día que lo a abandonado mandarle un mail recordatorio.

Mi tabla de carritos abandonados está así:

| id | token | id_usuario | id_producto | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fwgwe | 1 | 5 | 2021-02-26 17:23:44 |
| 1 | fwgwe | 1 | 35 | 2021-02-26 17:23:44 |

El `token` es algo que se genera en cada sesión, gracias a ello se lo puedo agregar todo al mismo usuario, esto lo guardo en la bd, si la compra se finaliza lo borro, y si no se finaliza se mantiene en está tabla.

Lo que pasa que ahora necesito que a este usuario le envié un mail a la hora que seria a las **18:23:44** y al día siguiente **2021-02-27 17:23:44**

Buscando por internet me encontré con esto: [Aquí](https://cvallejo.medium.com/cronjobs-laravel-585017b32862)

Según esto se pueden programar tareas en Laravel para hacer esto que quiero hacer, pero la verdad que no se muy bien como tengo que actuar. Alguien me que me pueda dar una sugerencia??

---

**Prueba**
He probado hacer un envío de email cada minuto para comprobar el funcionamiento y funciona correcto.

```
$schedule->call(function () {
  $totalUsers = \DB::table('users')
  ->whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')
  ->count();

  Mail::to('emailt@gmail.com')->send(new Carrito($totalUsers));
    logger('El sistema funciona!');
})->everyMinute();
```

Pero mi duda real es como hacer una query para comprobar y hacer el envío 1 hora después de estar el carrito abandonado y también al día siguiente.

Comment: Básicament, cron es un programador de tareas en sistemas *NIX, que ejecuta comandos de shell en intervalos específicos. El comando que tendría que ejecutar para el caso de laravel es `php artisan schedule:run`. Si no estás en un sitema *NIX, y por ejemplo estás en un windows, tienes el [programador de tareas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/taskschd/about-the-task-scheduler?redirectedfrom=MSDN) en reemplazo.

Comment: [Aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) la documentación oficial de laravel sobre el tema. Intenta correr cualquer tarea, aunque sea un `$schedule->call(function () { Log::info('tarea ejecutada '.now()->format('d/m/y H:i:s'); })->everyFiveMinutes();` y si te encuentras con algún obstáculo, comenta o actualiza la pregunta. Luego de tener funcionando eso puedes seguir con lo de los emails.

Comment: Hola @porloscerrosΨ gracias por tu respuesta, hoy me pongo con ello, aunque donde más me surge las dudas es en como hacer la query adecuada para consultar los datos y de ahí automatizar eso

Comment: Vale he realizado una pruebas de envio de email cada minuto, y funciona perfecto. Pero no consigo descifrar como hacer una query para que mande un mail a la 1hora y al día siguiente? Ahí tengo muchas dudas de como construir eso @porloscerrosΨ dejo en mi pregunta la prueba que he realizado.

Comment: Genial. No tengo como probarlo ahora, pero prueba si esta consulta te sirve `Modelo::where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereDate('created_at', now()->toDateString())->whereDate('created_at', now()->subDay()->toDateString());
    })
    ->whereTime('created_at', '>', now()->subHour(2)->startOfHour()->toTimeString())
    ->whereTime('created_at', '<=', now()->subHour()->startOfHour()->toTimeString())
    ->get();`

Comment: Hola @porloscerrosΨ el código que me pasas extrae unas fechas, pero tengo muchas dudas, no se si cuando estes disponible podemos pasar la conversación a un chat, sea la hora que sea, gracias!

Comment: Ok [traslademos la conversación al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120323/envio-de-mail-automaticos-en-laravel-5-8)

Answer (score 2):

como el cron se ejecuta cada segundo, puedes hacer una query como esta:

```
$notificationUsers = \DB::table('users')
->join('carts', 'carts.id_usuario', '=', 'users.id')
->whereRaw('DATE_ADD(carts.created_at,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) == NOW()')
->orWhereRaw('DATE_ADD(carts.created_at,INTERVAL 1 DAY) == NOW()')
->select('users.email', 'carts.id as cart_id')
->get();

foreach ($notificationUsers as $notificationUser){ 
    Mail::to($notificationUsers->email)->send(new Carrito());
}
```

Pero lo ideal es que crees un par de boleanos dentro de la tabla de los carritos abandonados para identificar si has enviado la notificación de la hora y la del día, puesto que si el cron en algún momento se detiene, habrán usuarios que nunca recibirán la notificación, eso te permitirá hacer lo siguiente:

```
$notificationUsers = \DB::table('users')
->join('carts', 'carts.id_usuario', '=', 'users.id')
->whereRaw('DATE_ADD(carts.created_at,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) >= NOW() && carts.hourly_notification == FALSE')
->select('users.email', 'carts.id as cart_id')
->get();

foreach ($notificationUsers as $notificationUser){ 
    Mail::to($notificationUsers->email)->send(new Carrito());

    $cart = Cart::find($notificationUser->cart_id);
    $cart->hourly_notification = 1;
    $cart->save(); 
}

$notificationUsers = \DB::table('users')
->join('carts', 'carts.id_usuario', '=', 'users.id')
->whereRaw('DATE_ADD(carts.created_at,INTERVAL 1 DAY) >= NOW() && carts.daily_notification == FALSE ')
->select('users.email', 'carts.id as cart_id')
->get();

foreach ($notificationUsers as $notificationUser){ 
    Mail::to($notificationUsers->email)->send(new Carrito());

    $cart = Cart::find($notificationUser->cart_id);
    $cart->daily_notification = 1;
    $cart->save(); 
}
```

Nota: el código anterior se puede refactorizar un poco para evitar hacer la query dos veces o incluso puedes sacar el update de carts del foreach para evitar la sobre carga de mysql al abrir y cerrar tantas conexiones (por cada iteración del foreach), creo que la idea queda mas o menos clara.

Comment: Hola @ManuelV muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, es muy elaborada y completa, te agradezco el esfuerzo. Si no te importa y tienes un hueco tengo algunas dudas, gracias! Luego lo pruebo el código

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo un poco sobre tu problema. Creo que al momento de llamar el método handle de tu job, debes evaluar si las órdenes de ese día tienen efectivamente la diferencia que requieres. Es decir, puedes hacer primero una relación con lo carritos y los usuarios. Suponiendo que un usuario solo puede tener un carrito y este solo puede tener un usuario, quedaría:

**User.php**

```
public function shoppingCart() {
    return $this->hasOne(Cart::class);
}
```

y **Cart.php**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

¿Por qué? Esto te ayuda a usar las cargas automáticas de Laravel y poder hacer algo como esto en el método handle del job que crees para ejecutar tu schedule automático:

**ShopingCartRememberJob.php**

```
public function handle(){

   $delayedCarts = Cart::with('user:id,email')
        ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::yesterday()->subHour()->toDateString())
        ->get();

   $delayedCarts->each(function ($cart, $key) {
       $date = Carbon::parse($cart->created_at);
       
       if(now()->greaterThan($date)){
           Mail::to($cart->user)->send(new NotificationCart());
       }
   });

}
```

Creo que eso sería básicamente todo. Incluso creo que podrías ahorrarte el if donde evalúas que el hoy es mayor que la fecha del carrito.